# Mouse Double-Clicking

Tags: mouse

I have a mouse that I think is 5 years old, where most times when I click, it automatically double-clicks.  If I click it just right, it will single click, but otherwise, it will perform a double-click.  I've tested it with multiple machines, and it's the same behavior.  I'm thinking that it's the contact wearing out or something, and is a hardware problem.  I think that makes sense since it doesn't work on multiple machines?

If there a way in windows to control the frequency of click?  Or is that typically defined in the mouse software?  I didn't find a setting in the mouse software for click speed.

Comment: Alternatively, what kind of mouse is it? Maybe you can open it (with the right instructions) to see whether you can fix it?

Comment: Microsoft Intellimouse Explorer 3.0... repair instructions seems beyond the user manual?  Do they typically have that info readily available?

Comment: Someone else on this site might have an idea.

Comment: There's a double click speed slider in the Control Panel in Windows, e.g. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/win_double_click.mspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The micro contact switch under the mouse button has a limited number of clicks. Basically its a very small convex metal bubble, that as you press down, it deforms enough to "snap" down and make contact. Releasing the pressure allows the metal to spring back. There is a little bit of plastic insulation that shields the sides of this semi-bubble. So after 10 gzillion clicks, the metal deforms a little and the insulation crudes up. The switch is insignificant in cost, but the effort of finding an acceptable tactile response is major. 
Mouse technology in the past few years has greatly improved, especially toward longer battery life and making the mice smaller and less klunky. Much more practical to replace it, like you would replace an old pen or pencil.

Comment: Could it be, by any chance, fixed by capacitor?